# Script to execute commands in the terminal

Tags: linux, bash

In fact I have a command line to run in a terminal to launch my Twitch point miner which has a graphical feedback in the terminal to know the number of points retrieved and other things.

But I have no idea how to put it in a .sh script

Here are the commands to execute in the terminal.

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv

source venv/bin/activate

cd /home/pi/Twitch-Channel-Points-Miner-v2

python run.py
```

If you can help me on this subject, it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Open a file named with `.sh`. Copy the lines from your post to the file. Save the file. You can use any file editor you want.

Comment: What specific problem stops you from doing this yourself? What do you mean by "in the terminal" that's distinct from how any other script works?

Comment: (Also, [using `.sh` -- or any other filename extension -- on scripts is bad practice; don't do it](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/)).

Comment: BTW, what's the point of having your script create a new virtualenv every time it's run? Ideally you should create your `venv` just once and reuse it as many times as you need.

Answer (score 0):

To create a script:

1. Open the terminal.
2. Go to a folder where you want to have the script `cd /path/to/folder`.
3. Create a new file using [vi](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html), [nano](https://www.nano-editor.org/) or any other editor. Put the commands in the file. For example, here I use the echo utility to put 2 echo commands into the my_script file `echo -e "echo 'command 1'\necho 'command 2'" > my_script`.
4. Add the execute permission to the file `chmod +x my_script`.
5. Execute the script using some shell, for example, bash `bash my_script`.
6. See the result:

```
command 1
command 2
```

Comment: `printf '%s\n' 'command 1' 'command 2'` is considerably less problematic (nonportable, runtime-setting-dependent) than `echo -e`. See also [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) on [unix.se].